# Can mpeg2 encode HD videos by changing the conffiguration parameters of its codec?

Tags: mpeg-2

Based on the setting of the configuration parameters of MPEG-2 codec I realized that it can encode HD video format but I am still in doubt. Is anybody sure if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doubting it?

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-2
- https://www.google.com/?q=MPEG-2%20codec%20+%20HD